# HTML Tables Problem, trying to answer assigment that talks about cellpading and cellspacing and rowspan and colspan

Tags: html

I'm learning HTML and i'm currently in tables section and while i'm doing some assignments, i found this problem and need someone to help me.

Assignment task in the picture, so that number 1 picture is assigment and my answer is number 2

so please i need someone to help

regards

thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjtVp.jpg)

I was trying to answer the assignment to be better and improve my self in HTML tables section.

I expect help because my friends told me about this amazing website that contains a lot of front end and back end developers.

Thank you.

Comment: Please see how to ask a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi and welcome, share a bit of code what have you tried, where did you fail.

Comment: That's iti think you can check .. 

https://codepen.io/MrTareQ/pen/dyqVEqm